# WooCommerce Subscriptions - change add to cart button text only when switching subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to know how to change the text of the add to cart button on the product page only when switching subscription? I actually made it work, but the standard 'Sign up now' text (within the standard woocommerce subscriptions options) is overriding the text after a second. I am now using this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_label_for_subscription_products', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_to_cart_label_for_subscription_products( $var, $instance ) {
    global $product;
    $product_type = $product->get_type();
    if ( isset( $_GET['switch-subscription']) ) {
        return __( 'Wijzig abonnement' );
    } else {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

So it looks like the code is working, but getting overruled or something.. How to give this code the highest priority so it overrules the standard 'Sign up now' text?

Comment: Try to change the hook priority `10` to an integer up like `90000`… Or if you want your hook to be triggered before use `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to use 1, but unfortunately no result.. What I find weird is that when I use 1, the script doesn't seem to work at all. I don't even see the new string coming up for 1 second.

When I use 90000 it does the same as with 10.. Any ideas?

Comment: This issue seems related to javascript that is appending the text…